# Я лично, мне лично

Tags: стилистика

Рэперы — это такая субкультура, с которой я не знаком. Я ничего не могу судить о них лично.

Не является ли это выражение лексически некорректным, потому что слова "я" и "лично" дублируют друг друга по смыслу?

Comment: "Ничего судить" — звучит не по-русски. Можно сказать "нисколько".

Answer (score 0):

Из словаря Кузецова:
лично
а) Сам (сама, сами), собственной персоной; персонально.
*Лично написал письмо.

Лично обратиться к администрации завода.

Лично сам решал задачи для сына.*
**б) *отт.* Непосредственно.**
*Сообщить **ему лично**.

Доложить лично генералу.

Вручить письмо лично адресату.

Лично меня это не касается.*

Синонимы *непосредственно*: *прямо, лично, напрямую*.

Возможно, что *лично* относится к *них*. То есть *о них непосредственно*.

Правильнее будет заменить *ничего* на *никак*.

В Нацкорпусе много примеров с *лично я / я лично*. Данное слово как бы усиливает местоимение, делая словосочетание аналогом *а вот я*.

Comment: В учебнике Тростенцовой и Ладыженской по русскому языку упоминалось о том, что следует избегать "Мне лично"

Comment: Не следует (в общем про "лично" при местоимениях). Но увлекаться точно не стоит. Здесь идёт усиление. Есть оттенок разговорности. Люди не говорят только на литературном языке. Если писать научную работу, то там следует избегать. Пример из словаря Ушакова: *Лично я ничего не имею против.* Но "мне лично" звучит как-то сленгово. Учебники, конечно, против сленга. Другое дело "лично мне".